# Making a dataframe from the list of the website

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe from this JSON https://stockrow.com/api/companies/AAPL/financials.json?ticker=AAPL&dimension=Q&section=Metrics

I am able to download the data and create a dataframe with 3 values. However, the dataframe only contain the data of last values. Here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

all_records = []
records = []
tickers = ['A','AAL','AAPL']

url_metrics = 'https://stockrow.com/api/companies/{}/financials.json?ticker={}&dimension=Q&section=Metrics'
indicators_url = 'https://stockrow.com/api/indicators.json'

# create a list from all tickers
for s in tickers:

    indicators = {i['id']: i for i in requests.get(indicators_url).json()}
    all_records = []
    for d in requests.get(url_metrics.format(s,s)).json():
        d['id'] = indicators[d['id']]['name']
        all_records.append(d)
    
graham_number = next(d for d in all_records if 'Graham Number' in d['id'])
earning_yield = next(d for d in all_records if 'Earnings Yield' in d['id'])
nav = next(d for d in all_records if 'Net Current Asset Value' in d['id'])

# extract data from all tickers list and convert to a dataframe 
for (k1, v1), (_, v2), (_, v3)  in zip(nav.items(), earning_yield.items(), graham_number.items()):
    if k1 in ('id'):
        continue

    records.append({
        'symbol' : s,
        'date' : k1,
        'net_current_asset_value': v1,
        'earnings_yield': v2,
        'gramham_number': v3
    })
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
df
```

output has only last value:

```
    symbol  date        net_current_asset_value earnings_yield  gramham_number
0   AAPL    2020-06-30  -104997000000.0         0.0364          17.692
1   AAPL    2020-03-31  -98222000000.0          0.0506          18.0426
2   AAPL    2019-12-31  -87856000000.0          0.0435          19.0755...
```

I want the output should have all values:

```
    symbol  date        net_current_asset_value earnings_yield  gramham_number
0   A       2020-06-30  -104997000000.0         0.0364          17.692
1   A       2020-03-31  -98222000000.0          0.0506          18.0426
2   A       2019-12-31  -87856000000.0          0.0435          19.0755...
3   AAL     2020-06-30  -104997000000.0         0.0364          17.692
4   AAL     2020-03-31  -98222000000.0          0.0506          18.0426
5   AAL     2019-12-31  -87856000000.0          0.0435          19.0755...
3   AAPL    2020-06-30  -104997000000.0         0.0364          17.692
4   AAPL    2020-03-31  -98222000000.0          0.0506          18.0426
5   AAPL    2019-12-31  -87856000000.0          0.0435          19.0755...
```

Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: I'm removing the [tag:web-scraping] tag since you're not pulling anything out of HTML, just using a JSON API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your indentation wrong:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

all_records = []
records = []
tickers = ['A','AAL','AAPL']

url_metrics = 'https://stockrow.com/api/companies/{}/financials.json?ticker={}&dimension=Q&section=Metrics'
indicators_url = 'https://stockrow.com/api/indicators.json'

# create a list from all tickers
for s in tickers:
    indicators = {i['id']: i for i in requests.get(indicators_url).json()}
    all_records = []
    for d in requests.get(url_metrics.format(s,s)).json():
        d['id'] = indicators[d['id']]['name']
        all_records.append(d)
    
    graham_number = next(d for d in all_records if 'Graham Number' in d['id'])
    earning_yield = next(d for d in all_records if 'Earnings Yield' in d['id'])
    nav = next(d for d in all_records if 'Net Current Asset Value' in d['id'])

    # extract data from all tickers list and convert to a dataframe 
    for (k1, v1), (_, v2), (_, v3)  in zip(nav.items(), earning_yield.items(), graham_number.items()):
        if k1 in ('id'):
            continue

        records.append({
            'symbol' : s,
            'date' : k1,
            'net_current_asset_value': v1,
            'earnings_yield': v2,
            'gramham_number': v3
        })
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
print(df)
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Print:

```
    symbol        date net_current_asset_value earnings_yield gramham_number
0        A  2020-07-31           -1320000000.0         0.0233        28.5032
1        A  2020-04-30           -1516000000.0         0.0288        27.6998
2        A  2020-01-31           -1551000000.0         0.0297        29.3613
3        A  2019-10-31           -1515000000.0         0.0448        33.9611
4        A  2019-07-31            -421000000.0         0.0486        33.9655
..     ...         ...                     ...            ...            ...
113   AAPL  2011-12-31            6144000000.0         0.0864          9.933
114   AAPL  2011-09-30            5232000000.0         0.0735         8.1677
115   AAPL  2011-06-30            9483000000.0         0.0763         7.4198
116   AAPL  2011-03-31           13570000000.0         0.0611         6.3801
117   AAPL  2010-12-31           11851000000.0         0.0564         5.5731

[118 rows x 5 columns]
```

And creates `data.csv`:

[image]

Comment: Hello Andrej. I tried to use this code to get data. However, it returned StopIteration error if I run the loop more than 100 tickers. I tried to use try and except method to ignore the error but didnt work. May I know the reason?

Comment: @janicewww Hello Janice. Without the stack trace is hard to guess where's the error. I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow where you put your code, full error message and describe the problem. That way more people can look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have your indentation wrong here:

```
graham_number = next(d for d in all_records if 'Graham Number' in d['id'])
earning_yield = next(d for d in all_records if 'Earnings Yield' in d['id'])
nav = next(d for d in all_records if 'Net Current Asset Value' in d['id'])

# extract data from all tickers list and convert to a dataframe 
for (k1, v1), (_, v2), (_, v3)  in zip(nav.items(), earning_yield.items(), graham_number.items()):
    if k1 in ('id'):
        continue
```

This needs to be under

```
for s in tickers:
```